# Replace iterators with slots

Tags: evaluation

Still trying to understand syntax for slots... How would I use slots to do this:

```
a = {
     {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6},    {7, 8, 9},    {10, 11, 12}},
     {{2, 4, 6}, {8, 10, 12},  {14, 16, 18}, {20, 22, 24}},
     {{3, 6, 9}, {12, 15, 18}, {21, 24, 27}, {30, 33, 36}}
    };

Show@ListPointPlot3D[Table[a[[i, j]], {i, {1, 2, 3}}, {j, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]]
```

[image]

I think it should look something like this:

```
 Show@ListPointPlot3D[a[[#1, #2]] & /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]
```

but that gives several errors which I'm not interpreting correctly so am unable to fix it.  Whereas I can see how this works:

```
Show@ListPointPlot3D[a[[#1]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}]
```

Comment: That's because `Map` doesn't construct the `Tuples` like `Table` does. You don't even need `Slot` or `Map` to do this, though, e.g. `Show@ListPointPlot3D[Extract[a, Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]]]`

Comment: I don't understand. With the a you define, Show@ListPointPlot3D[
  Table[a[[i, j]], {i, {1, 2, 3}}, {j, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]] is the same as ListPointPlot3D[a], so you do not need slots or a table.

Comment: I was trying to see how slots work as iterators, this probably isn't the best example though (as there is a lot of redundancy). Show@ListPointPlot3D[a[[#1]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}]   works, but Show@ListPointPlot3D[a[[#1, #2]] & /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}] doesn't.  I'll edit the question to show that's what I'm confused by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html):

```
ListPointPlot3D[Outer[a[[##]] &, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]]
```

For the specific example given you could also use `ListPointPlot3D[Array[a[[##]] &, {3, 4}]]`.

Regarding `##` see [`SlotSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html).  If arguments are not neatly in order the longer form will work, here `a[[#1, #2]] &`.